# Jade best practices for including JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, express, pug

I have a page-specific JavaScript code that gets loaded with that page. The problem is, it depends on jQuery. I placed `script(src='/js/lib/jquery.js')` at the end of **body**, as recommended.

Using this approach, I get `Can't find variable: $` because I am trying to execute page-specific JavaScript that depends on jQuery before jQuery is loaded.

Is there any way to make this work without moving `script(src='/js/lib/jquery.js')` to the **head** section?

I have even tried doing this, but I still get `Can't find variable: $`:

```
// layout.jade
script(src='/js/lib/jquery.js')
block scripts

// login.jade
block scripts
  script(type='text/javascript')
    $('form').validate();
```

**Edit**: *TJ Hollowaychuck* has posted a link here to a similar question, but those URLs is no longer valid: [Best practices for JavaScript in Jade templates](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/express-js/m110_-bHFT0/kBxbTSWBIR0J)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the updated URLs TJ was pointing to:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/jade/views/users/index.jade
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/jade/index.js#L34

However, I believe your real problem is on the client, not the server, where you want to wrap your jQuery inside of this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
});
```

Comment: That won't work. The problem is not with the DOM, but jQuery not being loaded first. $(document) still references the jQuery. The jquery-validate is a jQuery plugin, so order matters here.

Comment: If you view source on the page, does `<script src="/js/lib/jquery.js">` appear before your `<script>$('form')...`?

Comment: @MikeCauser No jQuery along with all other scripts are at the bottom of <body>. My page specific scripts that use jQuery are loaded before jQuery is loaded. I was just curious what do people do in this case? Put jQuery in the <head> block or keep in the <body> but then remove page-specific JS scripts and place them in one `main.js` and place it in the <body> after jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This is (part of) my layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content
    include scripts
    block scripts
```

I include a `scripts.jade` which contains my common scripts (like jQuery and configuration bits) and then all the scripts defined inside the single pages with a simple

```
block scripts
  script.
    alert("Hello!");
```